# Почему при отправке push-уведомления в event.data стоит null?

Tags: php, javascript

Отправляю уведомление через GCM

```
$msg = array(
'title' => 'This is a title. title',
'message' => 'here is a message. message',
);

$fields = array(
'registration_ids' => $r,
'data' => $msg,
);

$headers = array(
'Authorization: key=' . $gcm_auth_key,
'Content-Type: application/json',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Все успешно отправляется, принимаю сообщение в service worker по примеру https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/PushEvent

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
console.log(event);
});
```

Проблема в том что в примере данные берутся из event.data а у меня приходит event.data = null

В чем может быть причина и как получить текст сообщения внутри self.addEventListener('push'

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCM пока не поддерживает полезные данные с уведомлением. Mozilla да, Google Cloud Messaging - нет.

> you can’t send any data with a push message. Nope, nothing.

[отсюда](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en)

Comment: спасибо, подскажите еще как тогда реализовать показ
я из self.addEventListener('push', function(event) { делаю запрос на php скрипт в котором у меня массив с несколькими push уведомлениями, они показались, через время добавляется еще одна запись, а пуш опять показывает все что были и новую. Этого как то можно избежать или надо выводить только актуальные записи?

Comment: по ссылке всё показано, и этот момент тоже: при получении уведомления, ваш Web Worker должен запросить данные с сервера, или сам их подготовить, и только после готовности данных показать уведомление с этими данными.